# Does systeminfo command work for WIndows 2003?

Tags: operating-system

Is there a common command which can give the system information for windows2003 and above versions?

Answer (score 1):

I have used it many times with windows xp,2003,vista its works fine

Answer (score 0):

You also can script "system information acquisition" through WMI calls.

[image: WMI calls]

Use the **[WMIC Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&DisplayLang=en)** and a [little VB script](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/UsingWMI04052007222505PM/UsingWMI.aspx), and you can obtain precisely the informations you want/need, as opposed to the static `systeminfo` command.

For instance:

```
public string GetHardDisks() {
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new
    ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk"); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    foreach (ManagementObject wmi in searcher.Get()) {
        try {
            sb.Append("Drive Device ID: " +
            wmi.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID").ToString() +Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("Caption: " + wmi.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("Volume Serial Number: " + wmi.GetPropertyValue("VolumeSerialNumber").ToString()
            + Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append("Free Space: " + wmi.GetPropertyValue("FreeSpace").ToString() + "
            bytes free" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        catch {
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```